# Nested Li Elements Hover Alternate Background Color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's a quick overview of my problem.  I've got a list with **initial background *color 1*** like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1
    <ul>
    <li>Sub Item 1
        <ul>
            <li> Sub Sub Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is that, first level items (item 1, item 2), when hovered upon, has its background changed to *color two*.  Then when sub item 1,2 are hovered upon, the background color changed to *color 1*.  When sub sub item 1,2 get hovered upon, they changed to *color 2* and so on as the nesting goes deeper.  This means that for alternate levels of nesting, the background color alternates between two colors on hover as it goes deeper.

Any idea how to do this using jquery or css or both?

Comment: basically, I want the child background color to always contrast with the parent background color on hover, using only two colors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that multiple hover events are fired when you hover over sub items. Since the sub is a part of the parent element, the parent is technically getting hovered too. You can fix this by wrapping the text of each item in an inline element like span. Now each list item only activates one hover event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
.odd {color:red;}
.odd:hover, .odd:active{color:blue;}

.even{color:blue;}
.even:hover, .even:active{color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<ul>
<li><span class="odd">Item 1</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span class="even">Sub Item 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="odd"> Sub Sub Item 1</span></li>
            <li><span class="odd">Sub Sub Item 2</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="even">Sub Item 2</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span class="odd">Item 2</span></li>
</ul>


</html>
```

Comment: I understand this.  But for the deeply nested items, the hover color remains the same as the parent's one.

Comment: Hey I grokked your problem and changed my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with CSS. Give the main items a class of `main` and the sub items a class of `sub` and you can define

```
.main:hover
{
    color: Red;
}

.sub:hover
{
    color: Blue;
}
```